# The second dynamically loaded YouTube player object does not play

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Here is the problem in a nutshell:

When I load my page, I create one YouTube player object with YouTube's API, and it works great.

I have another YouTube player object dynamically created inside a carousel when the user click a play button. The object is created AND even appears in the carousel, but I can't access it's functions, like playVideo().

I have created an array of player objects AND an array of iframe IDs to pass into the new YT.Player object and all of that works, but the second video does not fire any of the events. When I inspect and step through the Javascript, I can see the properties of the player objects and I notice that the first one has all off the associated properties and functions, like addCueRange, isMuted, playVideo, etc. The second is missing all those. It has a very limited amount of properties.

One thing I notice is the property named "B". In the first one it is true, in the second one it's false. What does this property represent?

Here is part of the code:

```
var players = {};
var youTubeIframes = [];
var index = 0;
var videoID = "";

...

function addYouTubeEvents( youTubeIframe ) {
  youTubeIframes[index] = youTubeIframe;
  youTubeIframes[index].pauseFlag  = false;

  players[youTubeIframes[index].id] = new YT.Player( youTubeIframes[index], {
    videoId: videoID,
    playerVars: {
      html5: 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': function(e){
        onPlayerReady(e);
      },
      'onStateChange': function(evt){
        onStateChangeHandler( evt, youTubeIframes[index] );
      }
    }
  } );
  index++;
}
function onPlayerReady(e){
  console.log("Player is ready");
  if(e.target.a.id == 'youtube-video'){
    e.target.playVideo();
  }
}
```

Comment: on first view... id == 'youtube-video' ... if you are using duplicate id's then that's probably the dealbreaker

Comment: nope, each iframe has a unique id

Comment: I don't know the youtube api, so can't help you, but you may want to show your code for creating the object you pass into `addYouTubeEvents()` and some html markup. Also, how do you use `index` ?